# Why strcmp giving different response for complete filled character array?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
  char a[10]="123456789";
  char b[10]="123456789";
  int d;
  d=strcmp(a,b);

  printf("\nstrcmp(a,b) %d", (strcmp(a,b)==0) ? 0:1);
  printf("compare Value %d",d);
}
```

**Output:**

> strcmp(a,b) 0
>      compare value 0

If the same program response is different when increase the array to full value, I mean 10 characters. That time the values are different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
  char a[10]="1234567890";
  char b[10]="1234567890";
  int d;
  d=strcmp(a,b);

  printf("\nstrcmp(a,b) %d", (strcmp(a,b)==0) ? 0:1);
  printf("compare Value %d",d);
}
```

**Output:**

> strcmp(a,b) 1
>      compare value -175

Why `strcmp` responding differently when the string is reached full value of array ?

Comment: Use `strncmp`, which will allow the compiler to find array length. In this case, you overrun the array, as you are leaving no place for '\0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of your second snippet is undefined.

There's no room for the null-terminator, which is relied upon by `strcmp`, when you write `char a[10]="1234567890";`. This causes `strcmp` to overrun the array.

One remedy is to use `strncmp`.

Another one is to use `char a[]="1234567890";` (with `b` adjusted similarly) and let the compiler figure out the array length which will be, in this case, 11.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definitions of terms used in the C Standard (7.1.1 Definitions of terms)

> 1 Astring is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character....The length of a string is the
>   number of bytes preceding the null character and the value of a string
>   is the sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.

According to the description of function `strcmp`

> 2 The strcmp function compares **the string** pointed to by s1 to
>   **the string** pointed to by s2.

According to the section 6.7.9 Initialization Of the Standard

> 14 An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating
>   null character** if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

In the first program arrays `a` and `b` initialized by string literals have room to store the terminating zero.

```
char a[10]="123456789";
char b[10]="123456789";
```

Thus the array contain `string` and the function `strcmp` may be applied to these arrays.

In the second program arrays `a` and `b` do not have a room to store the terminating zero

```
char a[10]="1234567890";
char b[10]="1234567890";
```

So the arrays do not contain strings and the function `strcmp` may not be applied to the arrays. Otherwise it will have undefined behaviour because it will stop when it finds either non-equal characters beyond the arrays (because the arrays have all equal characters) or a terminating zero.

You could get a valid result if you limit the comparison with the sizes of the arrays. To do that you have to use another standard function `strncmp`

Its call can look for example the following way

```
strncmp( a, b, sizeof( a ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare and initialize your array with string literal(*but no space for nul termiantor*) and also string manipulation function requires C-style string to be passed as argument (terminated with `'\0'`) .

So ,in your second program your arrays -

```
char a[10]="1234567890";
char b[10]="1234567890";
```

There is no space for `'\0'` character , so this invokes undefined behavior.

Increase size of your arrays -

```
char a[11]="1234567890";          //or char a[]="1234567890";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second case,

```
char a[10]="1234567890";
char b[10]="1234567890";
```

you arrays are not null-terminated, so they cannot be used as *strings.* Any function operating on string family will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), (as they will go past the allocated memory *in search of* the null-terminator).

You better be using

```
char a[ ]="1234567890";
char b[ ]="1234567890";
```

to leave the size allocation to the compiler to avoid the null-termination issue. Compiler will allocate enough memory to hold the supplied initializer as well as the terminating null.

That said, `void main()` should br `int main(void)` at least to conform to the standards.